# Finding set of values for given inequality.

Tags: inequality, modules

I was solving a question from the book **Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics** *by V Krishnamurthy* and got stuck and confuse at the end.

The question is find the set of values of $x$ for which the given inequality is true. $\mid x^2+3x\mid \ge 2-x^2$

**My attempts:**

1) If $x^2+3x\ge 0$  $x^2+3x \ge 2-x^2 \implies 2x^2+3x-2\ge 0 \implies (x+2)(2x-1)\ge 0 \implies x\le -2, x\ge \frac 12$

2) If $x^2+3x\lt 0\implies x\le \frac{-2}{3}$

$x\le -2$ and $x\le \frac{-2}{3}\implies x\le -2$  So my answer is $x\le -2, x\ge \frac 12$  but when I checked $\frac{-2}{3}$ is also a solution and  $x=-2 \implies x^2+3x=-2\lt 0$ but it should be positive. Please clarify this to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You must reconcile your solutions against the assumptions you make. In case one, you are **assuming** that $x^2+3x=x(x+3)\geq0$. So you must throw out the interval $(-3,-2]$ from that case. Look carefully at your second case, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $x^2+3x \ge 0$, then $x \ge 0$ or $x\le -3.$
- Upon solving $x^2+3x \ge 2-x^2$ and combine with the condition above, the answer is $x \le -3$ or $x \ge \frac12$.
- If $x^2 + 3x < 0$, then $-3<x<0$.
- Upon solving $-x^2-3x \ge 2-x^2$ and combine with the condition above, the answer is $-3<x\le-\frac23$.
- Combining the second and fifth point, the solution is $$\{x:x \le -3\} \cup \{x:-3<x \le -\frac23\} \cup\{x:x \ge \frac12\}=  \{x:x \le -\frac23\} \cup\{x:x \ge \frac12\} $$